# could not modify view after calling ajax from controller using a factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a demo app through which I want to display all countries data in a page(view) using angularjs.

Here is my code:

MyApp.js

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", [ 'ui.bootstrap', 
                                'ngRoute',
                                'MyControllers',
                                'MyFactory' ]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'MyController',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/homeView/homeView.jsp'
        })
        .when('/view1', {
            controller: 'MyController',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/view1/view1.jsp'
        })
        .when('/view2', {
            controller: 'MyController',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/view2/view2.jsp'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

MyControllers.js

```
var controllers = angular.module('MyControllers', []);

controllers.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'Factory', 
    function($scope, Factory) {
        $scope.countries = [];
        $scope.showme = false;

        $scope.CountryDetailsClick = function() {
            var responsePromise = Factory
             .getResponse("http://localhost:12345/DemoNew/getCountryList");

            responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers,
                    config) {
                $scope.countries = data;
                console.log("countryList size = " + $scope.countries.length);
                $scope.showme = true;
            });

            responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers,
                    config) {
                alert("AJAX failed");
            });
        }
}]);
```

MyFactory.js

```
var myFactory = angular.module('MyFactory', []);
myFactory.factory('Factory', function($http) {
return {
    getResponse : function(url) {
        return $http.get(url);
    }
}
});
```

View1.jsp

```
<body ng-view>
    <h1 class="page-header">View1</h1>
    {{countries.length}}
</body>
```

View2.jsp

```
<body ng-view>
    <h1 class="page-header">View2</h1>
    {{showme}}
</body>
```

homeView.jsp

```
<body ng-view>
<h1 class="page-header">Home</h1>
```

index.jsp

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation"
        style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <a href="#/view2" ng-click="CountryDetailsClick()">Country Details</a>
            <a href="#/view1"> Country Rate Plans</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="page-wrapper"  ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I am getting on console as :-

countryList size = 268

which is correct, I am using spring for backend. I am able to fetch data from the database.

But in View1 I get:

0

Also in View2 I get:

false

That means I am not able to reflect the fetched data to the view. Please help :(

===============================================================

After suggestions given by rob, i changed the following:

I changed my MyFactory.js to:

```
var myFactory = angular.module('MyFactory', []);
myFactory.factory('Factory', function($http) {

var current = {};

var factory = {
    getResponse: function(urlReq){
        var data = $http({method: 'GET', url: urlReq}).then(function (result){
            current = result.data;
        }, function (result){
            alert("ERROR: No data returned");
        });
    },
    getList: function(){
        return current;
    }
}
return factory;
});
```

And MyControllers.js to:

```
var controllers = angular.module('MyControllers', []);

controllers.controller('MyController', 
    function($scope, Factory) {
       $scope.CountryDetailsClick = function() {
       Factory.getResponse("http://localhost:12345/DemoNew/getCountryList");
       }

    });

    controllers.controller('MyController3',  
         function($scope, Factory) {
         console.log("in controller3");
    });

    controllers.controller('MyController2',  
        function($scope, Factory) {
        console.log("in controller2");
        $scope.countries = Factory.getList();
        $scope.showme = true;
    });
```

MyApp.js

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'MyController',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/homeView/homeView.jsp'
        })
        .when('/view1', {
            controller: 'MyController3',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/view1/view1.jsp'
        })
        .when('/view2', {
            controller: 'MyController2',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/view2/view2.jsp'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

View2.jsp

```
<body ng-view>
    <h1 class="page-header">View2</h1>
    {{showme}}
    {{countries}}
</body>
```

When I click on Country Details, I get "true" and an empty array, but when I click Country Details after clicking Country Rate Plans, it works perfectly fine.

Please find the flaw.!!

Comment: not sure if this is causing your problem but you don't need `ng-view` in any of your views. You just need it in index.jsp

Comment: @rob: thanks for pointing the mistake out, removed it but the main problem isn't yet solved, still could not load the view.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same controller from index.jsp and from your views. So Angular is creating two instances of your controller each with it's own scope. You are calling `CountryDetailsClick()` from the `ng-controller` in index.jsp's scope but you are trying to show the value of `countries.length` from the view's scope.

If you want to share some functionality or state between different controllers (e.g. your `CountryDetailsClick()` function) then put it in a service.

Comment: thanx for the reply, i am having problem in understanding the concept. Can you show me the workaround for this please.?